# Does continuous distribution function mean continuous random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose for a random variable $X$, we have a continuous distribution function. Can we say from it that it is a continuous random variable?

I, personally think that, as distribution function is continuous, mass at each point is $0$. Also as distribution function is continuous, it can be broken into intervals where the function is differentiable in each interval which will give the density function. However, I am not sure whether any continuous function "can be broken into intervals where the function is differentiable in each interval"

Comment: There are a million definitions out there of a "continuous" random variable. What is the definition given in your book?

Comment: @user180040 , I would like to hear two definitions (along with their sources) which do not imply each other.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function $\;$

Comment: Here are three I've seen in probability books: 1) The cumulative distribution function is continuous. 2) There exists a density function p(x) for the distribution, that is, an integrable function $p$ such that $P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b p(x) \, dx$ 3) The range of the random variable $X$ contains an interval of real numbers. This is not to mention the fact that there are Riemann-integrable functions, Lebesgue-integrable, and others.

Comment: 2) http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~fribergh/course5.pdf 3) Book by Montgomery and Runger 1) http://books.google.ca/books?id=CkEm-Yil9LsC&lpg=PA276&dq=%22continuous%20random%20variable%22%20definition&pg=PA276#v=onepage&q=%22continuous%20random%20variable%22%20definition&f=false

Comment: @user180040 , 1 and 2 are equivalent : [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) Also 3 is not at all a standard definition. There are many shortcomings of it.

Comment: No, "absolutely continuous" is not the same as continuous. I don't like (3) at all either. But could you please provide the definition that *you* are using of a continuous random variable?

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty You already said it twice but this is quite wrong: no, the CDF being continuous does not imply that a PDF exists.